# Phantom start-up program

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

I opened up Task Manager this morning to find a nameless program listed in the Start-Up Programs.

[image]

I am also unable to locate it by right clicking on it:

[image]

**How can I find out what this is?** I assume it's a remnant of something I have uninstalled. The only thing I can rememeber doing is recently installing Cerebro and then uninstalling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found that it is indeed Cerebro. If you right click on the tabs you can select "Command Line" and it will display the source.

[image]